# Team and Groups members out-of-sync

Tags: microsoft-graph, office-365-groups, microsoft-teams

I have created about 800 Microsoft Teams in a tenant and have some inconsistent behavior regarding the Team Members/Owners versus Group Members/Owners.

When adding members/owners to a Office 365 Group they appear as Microsoft Team members/owners after some delay (typically about 1 - 2 hours). On some Groups this does not happen.

My question basic question is why are the members/owners in sync for some Teams/Groups and not for others? Are others experiencing the same inconsistency? Are there work-arounds other than managing the members/owners on Teams in order to have consistent members/owners across Teams and Groups?

Here is how we created the Teams:

1. Create Office 365 using Graph API (groups endpoint) with app-only permissions with no members and only one owner
2. Group owner logs into Teams client and migrates the Group to a Team
3. Group members are added using Graph API (groups endpoint) with app-only permissions or via Groups User Interface in Outlook (logged-in as Group owner)

I created a support cases with Office 365 support and learned that Teams and Groups are regarded as separate/disconnected entities and therefore the Group members/owners are not 'replicated' to the corresponding Team. But Team members/owners are always replicated to the corresponding Group.

Answer (score 0):

We also experience inconsistencies: We create Teams, then add Users to the corresponding Group. They appear in the Admin Console as part of the Group. But in Teams they do not appear. Only if removed and added inside the Admin console they are also part of the Team (but of course this is not doable for thousands of users...)

**The solution**

Our solution was to replace "old" Graph API calls with the new `beta` API.

So instead of

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/owners/$ref`

we use the `beta` API like so:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{groupId}/owners/$ref`

Only the `beta` version of the API seems to also add the users to the Team while the `v1.0` only adds it to the Group but not to the corresponding Team.